# in tree i got erro no matching function for call to function but i made it properly using template

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
template <typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T> takeinput();

template <typename T>
BinaryTreeNode<T>* take_input()
{
    T rootdata;

    cout << "enter data ";
    cin >> rootdata;

    if(rootdata == -1 || rootdata == 'n') {
        return nullptr;
    }

    BinaryTreeNode<T>* root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(rootdata);

    root->left = takeinput(); // got error in this line
    root->right = takeinput();

    return root;
}
```

> ```
> [Error] no matching function for call to 'takeinput()'
> [Note] candidate is
> [Note] template<class T> BinaryTreeNode<T> takeinput()
> [Note] template argument deduction/substitution faile
> [Note] couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
> ```

in this I got an error for no matching call for function take input 
but I made it properly

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please read this about a [MCVE], and edit your question to fit that mold.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that template argument cannot be deduce by the expression in the left side of the assingment.

```
root->left = takeinput();
```

The `takeinput` function need template parameter:

```
root->left = takeinput<T>();
```